# (400) Bad Request when trying to send an image to my custom AutoML model via the REST API

Tags: json, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, automl

I'm trying to implement my custom AutoML model in C# by sending images via the REST API, but I keep getting different errors.

The one I currently have is:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

I have taken an image and converted into a string of bytes called `byteString` and have created the jsonRequest object like this:

`string jsonRequest = "{\"payload\":{\"image\":{\"imageBytes\":\"" + byteString + "\"},}}";`

Then I'm doing a POST request like follows:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(@"https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/us-central1/models/MODEL_ID:predict");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer GCLOUD_ACCESS_TOKEN");

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(jsonRequest);
}
```

Then when it hits `request.GetResponse();` if gives me the above error with no other information.

For reference, these are the snippets taken from the bottom of the PREDICT page on my custom AutoML model:

**request.json:**

```
{
  "payload": {
    "image": {
      "imageBytes": "YOUR_IMAGE_BYTE"
    },
  }
}
```

**Execute the request:**

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
  https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/us-central1/models/MODEL_ID:predict -d @request.json
```

Thanks guys, been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: How do you produce the image bytestring? Also, this might sound redundant, but have you made sure to pass the correct values for PROJECT_ID and MODEL_ID?

Comment: Have you had any luck figuring this out? I have been scouring the web for a solution the same exact issue and just came across your post here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to base64 the byte string? This is mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.models/predict#Image).

Answer (score 0):

In my use case, I share my vision model to my colleagues by creating a service account for them with the right role and give them this URL for prediction:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer add_access_token " -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/id_project/locations/us-central1/models/:model_idpredict -d @path_of_file_image_in_base64
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with RestSharp(https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp) library

Example:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{project-id}/locations/us-central1/models/{model-id}:predict":
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("authorization", $"Bearer {Access-Token}");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"payload\":{\"image\":{\"imageBytes\":\"{Image-Base64}""}}}", ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```